# Harvest time not adding up anymore in Asana

Tags: asana, harvest

My company uses Asana for task management and Harvest for time tracking. We have time tracking set up on all our tasks from within Asana. Normally by clicking the timer on a task I can see how much time I've spent on a particular task.

Yesterday this suddenly stopped and I am no longer able to see how much time I've spent on a task most of the time (occasionally it will work, but very rarely)

Has anyone else had this issue before and solved it? I'm hoping that it's not a feature that has been removed because I use it constantly to make sure I stay within time budget for specific tasks (it's much easier to track total time on a task than through harvest).

To be clear, this is what I'm seeing: [image: What I See]

...and this is what I expect to see: [image: What I expect to see] (screen via https://blog.asana.com/2013/08/harvesttimetracking/)

**Edit**
I just noticed that Asana will show the total time of a task I am currently tracking (as in timer actively running) rather than allow me to see current time tracked for any item (which it used to).

Comment: Good call. Added. Seems I'm too used to trying to keep email file size down that I automatically fall back to cloud app for screen sharing ;)